# How to fix screen size compatible to all android device in android?

Tags: android, size, screen, device

I have an `application with some buttons`. The button `styles are xml gradients`. When running this app in `3.2 QVGA emulator` the widgets goes outside to the view like this

**Emulator screen shot:**

[image: emulator screen shot]

While running on a 5 inch display device I have getting complete view.

**Device screen shot:**

[image: device screen shot]

How can I fix this issue by support all screen size compatibility?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/imageExpense"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="95dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/add_btnstyle"
                android:gravity="center|bottom"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Expense" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/imageIncome"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="95dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/add_btnstyle"
                android:gravity="center|bottom"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Income"
                android:textAlignment="gravity" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageExpense"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:src="@drawable/expense" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageIncome"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:src="@drawable/income" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/imageReport"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="95dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/add_btnstyle"
                android:gravity="center|bottom"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Report" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewRep"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="57dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/pie_chart" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/imageSettings"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="95dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/add_btnstyle"
                android:gravity="center|bottom"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Settings" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageSettings"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/system_config_services" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imageAbout"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/settings_add_btnstyle"
            android:text="Log Off" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Powered by Microclouds India Pvt Ltd"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you can simply go through -http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: i think you have a problem with the layout xml...can you post your layout xml?

Comment: @HamidShatu added xml code into my question..

Answer (score 0):

use vertical `<ScrollView>` 
Find tutorial of scrollview on http://sampleprogramz.com/android/scrollview.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:padding="20dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="expense"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="income"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear1"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="report"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="20dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="settings"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:text ="log out"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create different Layouts for different devices:

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For phones
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets
```

device will automatically load the relevant layout according to device size.